# can I use age and year fixed effects at the same time?

Tags: categorical-data

I have an unbalanced panel dataset. I want to know the effect of the RS on log income. I put year dummies and PMSA dummies in the regression. Should I also control age here? (Different individuals have different ages at the beginning.)

[image]

Comment: If everyone were born in the same year, then age, year, and a constant would be collinear. If people are born in different years, then they aren't collinear. This is purely a linear-algebra comment, and I have no idea what makes sense for your particular problem.

Answer (score 1):

- If everyone were born in the same year, then age, year, and a constant would be collinear.
- If people are born in different years, then they aren't collinear.

This is purely a linear-algebra comment. 
I have no idea what makes sense for your particular problem.

Comment: Hi Matthew, I posted a related question recently: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/503116/the-effect-of-age-in-panel-data-when-adding-year-dummies . I assume that although you note in your second point that age and year would not be perfectly collinear, there could still be an issue of disentangling the two effects right?

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes, you can. It does not have much more information than age at the beginning of the observation(of age is in years and observations are yearly in your panel), but if it is assumed to change the outcome variable and it is correlated with the RS, you should include it.

In case of perfect multicollinarity your statistical software will drop it anyway.

Comment: The year should be included as dummuies, otherwise you will end up with perfect collinarity - since the change will be same and = 1 for all.

Comment: Well that he already states in his question.