# The effect of age in panel data, when adding year dummies

Tags: r, time-series, panel-data, age

I have a question that is slightly related to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/162111/can-i-use-age-and-year-fixed-effects-at-the-same-time). I think my issue however requires a closer look because in my case, `age` is not the control variable, but the variable of interest.

I have panel data set in which I am trying to evaluate the effect of the `mean_age` of some geographic areas on my dependent variable (expecting a positive relationship). The standard is to **include** year dummies:

Running without year dummies:

```
Result_A <- plm(y ~ mean_age + A + B + C, index=c("ID", "year"), data=data, model = c("within"))

Coefficients:
                   Estimate  Std. Error t-value            Pr(>|t|)    
mean_age         0.27012828  0.02376204   11.37 <0.0000000000000002 ***
```

But when accounting for years:

```
Result_B <- plm(y ~ mean_age + A + B + C + as.factor(year), index=c("ID", "year"), data=data, model = c("within"))
                    Estimate   Std. Error t-value            Pr(>|t|)    
mean_age            -0.032474250  0.003036899  -10.69 <0.0000000000000002 ***
```

I found out that age is positively correlated with years (apparently people are living longer), which might explain the problem I have:

```
Call:
lm(formula = mean_age ~ year, data = data)
            Estimate Std. Error t value            Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  37.8796     0.0552   686.1 <0.0000000000000002 ***
year2006      1.2119     0.0781    15.5 <0.0000000000000002 ***
year2011      1.4827     0.0781    19.0 <0.0000000000000002 ***
year2017      2.5417     0.0781    32.5 <0.0000000000000002 ***
```

I am trying to evaluate age differences caused by migration and not an aging population. Is there a way to get a clean `age` effect, and still being able to include year dummies? If not, would excluding the year dummies completely invalidate my result?

I tried to subtract the year coefficients from the mean age, but that does not do anything (identical results). The same goes for using the residuals from `lm(formula = mean_age ~ year, data = data)` instead.

Comment: Sounds like unsurprising collinearity. As I understand your data problem, you're looking at the average age of a population in 2001 (?), 2006, 2011, and 2017. The issue is that these observations are going to autoregressive: the population in 2006 will strongly predict the population in 2011 (unless there is some significant event affecting birth rates, death rates, or immigration/emigration). I'm not familiar enough with the plm() function to know whether year needs to be included as both a predictor and index variable, so I can't say what would be appropriate on that end